# How to edit or change font anti-aliasing settings for Aptana Studio 3 for windows?

Tags: java, aptana, antialiasing

I cannot find any font anti-aliasing settings in Aptana. Is it even possible?

Comment: It should follow the OS's settings. http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/discussion/293649/thread/5e4e31b9